# Vungle ads sometimes not caching - Corona

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk, vungle-ads

I've integrated Vungle video ads in my Corona Game it was working perfect but few days ago it stopped caching video ads completely, but after few days it stared it self without changing any thing in code. Now it again stopped caching video ads. I suspect this issue is either from Corona or Vungle side but am not sure.

```
local vungleInterstitial = "540e9681c7ec2b6d4400000e" 
local videoCompletedCallback=nil


videoAddListener=function( event )

    if (event.isError ) then
        --Cached video ad not available for display
        print("problem to show ad")
    elseif event.type == "cachedAdAvailable" then
        print("cachedAdAvailable")
    elseif tostring(event.type) == "adView" then
        print("called when add is viewed")
    elseif  event.type == "adStart" then
        print("Corona ads started")
        audio.pause()
    elseif event.type == "adEnd" then
        print("Corona ads ended")
        videoCompletedCallback()
        audio.resume()
    end
end


    showVideoAd = function(callbackFunc)
        print("showVideoAd function called")
        videoCompletedCallback=callbackFunc;
        if ( vads.isAdAvailable() ) then
            print(" if ( vads.isAdAvailable() ) then, is true")
            print("vads.show")
            vads.show( "interstitial", { isBackButtonEnabled = false } )
        else
             local alert = native.showAlert( "Video Ad", "The Video Ad is not available at the moment. Please Try after some time.", { "OK" } )
        end 
    end

    vads.init("vungle",vungleInterstitial,videoAddListener)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to geo or daily view limits. Try with vungleTest as your AppID.